# Draw DAGs with Javascript tool

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm newbie ... can someone guide me to any tool to draw Aciclic Directed Graphs?

I need a tool that gets as input a json file and draws dags.
I'm using Spring MVC to build my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library that may have the tools you're looking for:

http://sigmajs.org/

Specifically from the documentation:
https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Graph-API